# add and remove same css class instantly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have simple html with `div` and `button`. Also i have a css class with CSS3 Transition:

```
.animate
{
    -webkit-animation-name: animation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;   
}
```

I want to start animation by clicking a button. So, i wrote a script, which instantly remove and add again `.animate` class to div, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Check it out:

```
("#button").click(function(){ 
    startAnimation(); 
    });

    function startAnimation()
    {
        if ($("#test-div").hasClass('animate')==true)
        {
            $("#test-div").removeClass('animate');  
            startAnimation();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#test-div").addClass('animate'); 
        }   
    }
```

Why jquery can't remove and instantly add same class? How can i fix that?

And maybe, there is another way to start css3 transition by clicking any selector?

Thanks.

**UPD.** I upload script at [jsfiddle.net/PfzZN/1/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/PfzZN/1/)

Comment: I think you will have an easier time using animation in JavaScript then trying to have fine grained control over CSS animations.

Comment: Why don't you just **not** add the class if it's already there?

Comment: This would be easier for us to debug if you created a jsFiddle with the relevant code :)

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't happend? I think that code will run too fast for you to notice any changes

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: if add class when selector already had it, then animation just won't start

Comment: How does adding the class cause an animation?

Comment: i mention that in post. there is css rule for that: every selector that had 'animate' class doing animation once

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the script that makes the change to DOM is in the same thread, for some reason the change will not apply until the thread is finished. So going by your way, the browser will see as if nothing has happened because the 'animate' class is removed and added in the same thread.

As a workaround, will this be good enough?

```
function startAnimation()
{  
    $("#flash-message").removeClass('animate');  
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#flash-message").addClass('animate')
    },1);  
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver. I was searching for this answer for three straight days. Thanks a ton.  I have a pinch of knowledge on jQuery.  I tried many ways like adding and removing the classes in same condition, toggling the same class but nothing worked like a charm like this does. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

(My original answer was "deleted" via editing, because it was just plain wrong.)

This seems somewhat like a legitimate bug in Webkit's implementation, or at least something very unexpected. Because if you do a `setTimeout`, like so:

```
function startAnimation()
{
    $("#flash-message").toggleClass('animate');    
    if (!$("#flash-message").hasClass('animate'))
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $("#flash-message").addClass('animate');    
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

Then it works. That is, delaying the addition of the class until later seems to make Webkit realize it should re-start the animation.

Not a great solution, but the fact that it was a 1-millisecond `setTimeout` means at least it's not a timing issue... pretty weird, though.

Comment: Read again my post. i don't need "magically undo", i just need to repeat same animation every time i clicked a button (and i animate `div`, not `button`). `toggleClass` make it work, but only on every second click. That's why i'm trying to use my script, to make animation in one click —  reset css for selector by `removeClass`, and instantly set it again by `addClass`.

Comment: If `toggleClass` makes it work (even if only every other time), then I think _my_ understanding of the animation system is flawed, and I should delete this post.

Comment: take a look it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/PfzZN/ . Will work only in webkit-based browser, of course

Comment: Animation will start as soon as the class is applied, and lasts as long as the class exists. If you remove the class immediately, the animation resets. Try clicking the toggle button quickly to see what I mean.

Comment: I didn't solve the problem, but got some insight here... http://jsfiddle.net/PfzZN/5/

Comment: OK, I updated that fiddle to include a working solution, and updated my answer to explain the basics of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JS to listen for animation events.  This is tricky, but better than arbitrary timeouts etc that may have no bearing on your animation in the future.  Check this out:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-events-